# What are the most important patterns for line of business web-applications?

Tags: design-patterns

What are the most important patterns you should know, when developing testable n-tier [line of business](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_business) web applications?

- Repository pattern
- Model View Controller
- Dependency Injection Pattern
- Factory Pattern
- Singleton

What else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"most" important?

The problem domain's patterns -- whatever they are.  Accounts Payable, General Ledger, Accounts Receivable, Organizational Hierarchy.

http://www.businessanalysisbooks.com/0471295515.html

[http://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Patterns-Reusable-Addison-Wesley-Technology/dp/0201895420](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201895420)

Technical patterns (MVC, Repository, etc.) are a dim second place.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asking about the connection between design patterns and best practice for business, there is a bit of subjectivity you have to deal with. I would focus entirely on making your code easy to understand and reuse.

I would focus less on design patterns (no single pattern is better than another) and instead focus on some basic tenets of design:

- Use self-documenting coding
  conventions (so you don't have to
  document at all, the code is just
  understandable).
- Don't repeat yourself (DRY)
- Use Object Oriented Programming
  techniques (don't just use objects as
  a container for functions)

If you must know the patterns that are most effective in almost every business situation, here they are:

- MVC - This gives you the ability to separate your code into easily maintainable pieces
- Factory Pattern - Provides the ability to use logic in determining how an object should be created
- Singleton - Particularly useful with database connection objects
- Active Object - Makes life much easier when you don't have to worry about state persistence.

Answer (score 0):

short answer: **it depends**